# Looking for this light novel named "The Seven Heroes"

Tags: story-identification, demons, heroes

*The Seven Heroes* is a fantasy adventure light novel that follows the story of a gamer who gets transported to an alternate world and finds himself as the second of seven heroic figures. He must overcome incredible odds and protect the people of his new world from complete destruction.

Where can I read this light novel?

Comment: Just to be clear, since the term gets used interchangeably, is this a paper comic, an online comic, or written word?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Or is it something you've only heard about?  (Please note that we can't help you find pirated copies of works.)

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: And my apologies if I missed the point of the question, and there's an actual story out there named "The Seven Heroes" that you were just trying to find a way to legally procure.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes I am trying to find a legal way to read this light novel. Sorry for late message as this post did not get many views in the first place I simply lost hope in getting the answer from here.

Comment: Is the work the same one mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for *[Monogatari no Kuromaku ni Tensei shite](https://myanimelist.net/manga/153783/Monogatari_no_Kuromaku_ni_Tensei_shite)*, aka *Reincarnated as the Mastermind of the Story*.

> There was a globally popular game called "The Legend of the Seven Heroes." Ren cleared the sequel of that game at the fastest record in the world, and thus he obtained bonus special data. However, no matter where he looked inside the game, he could not find the data. The moment Ren was about to give up on the search, he decided to start playing the second round of the game. Suddenly, a notification message "Do you want to start a special story?" appears on the screen. When Ren chooses "Yes" without hesitation, he loses consciousness, and when he woke up, he was a baby.
>
> Could it be that he was reincarnated as one of the heroes in "The Legend of the Seven Heroes"? Ren, who thought such a thing was impossible, could not believe his ears when he heard his name from his mother's mouth. It was the name of a classmate who betrays the heroes in the middle of the story. Of course, he wishes to live in peace. But in the game, he meets a saint whose life he's supposed to take, and doesn't. Furthermore, he ends up saving a character (the boss of a great noble family) who was supposed to die.
>
> All of these things create a development that he doesn't know about...

The official serial release of the novel can be found [here](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/16816700427572694145) in Japanese. I don't believe there is an official English translation yet, although I know fan translations exist. If you are looking for the manga, it looks like it's being released via *[Dengeki no Shin Bungei](https://dengeki.fandom.com/wiki/Dengeki_Bunko#Dengeki_no_Shin_Bungei)*.

Found with a search for `"light novel" "the seven heroes"`